# Mobile Bootstrap nav not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when you make the nav bar mobile screen size, the 3 line thing at the top right won't work. Any reason why? Thanks. I was using Google Chrome when changing the side. The JS and BootStrap versions both match, v3.0.3.

```
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MC.FastFoodCraft.COM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#donate">Donate</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="" name="servers" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Servers <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#factions">Factions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#teampvp">TeamPvP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skywars">SkyWars</a></li>
                <li><a href="#prison">Prison</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hub">Hub</a></li>
              </ul>
              <li><a href="/bans">Bans</a></li>
              <li><a href="/vote">Vote</a></li>
              <li><a href="/forum">Forums</a></li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /navbar wrapper -->
```

Thanks -FRED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this

```
    <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

change that to this

```
   <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

Comment: did it work? kindly mark it as an answer to close it

Comment: No problem. SO is made for that. Cheers!